# Populate PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html, gallery, populate

I current am trying to populate a gallery from the php code.  Looking at firebug the code is firing and running correctly except it is writing the code in the file dyna.php instead of index.html  How do I get it to populate in a specific div in index.html.

Also, how do I get it to only auto create the `<li>` tag and not the `<ul>` tag.

**dyna.php**

```
<?
session_start();
$database = mysql_connect( "localhost", "groupsix_001", "4312001" );    

mysql_select_db( "groupsix_user_information", $database );
$getimg = mysql_query("SELECT imagename FROM images WHERE categoryid = '38'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getimg))
{
    echo "<ul id='gallery'>".
    "<li class='loaded'>" . 
    "<a href='/IMAGES/". $row['imagename'] .">" . "</a>".
    "</li>
    </ul>"
    ;
}
?>
```

I have jquery that runs the **dyna.php** when a button is clicked.

I want to insert it into my

```
<div id="gallery"> </div>
```

jquery

```
function dosomething(){
  $.get("Gallery/dyna.php");
  return false;
};
```

Comment: You can't include php-code inside a html-file. You must do the other way around . Include html inside your php-file.

Comment: Post your `jQuery` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this

**HTML** (Assuming you have a button with id `getImages`)

```
<button id="getImages"></button>
<div id="gallery"> </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#getImages').on('click', function(){
        $.get("Gallery/dyna.php", function(data){
            $('#gallery').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
// ...
$getimg = mysql_query("your query");
if($getimg)
{
    // ID should be unique, so use 'gallery_inner' because parent div's ID is gallery
    echo "<ul id='gallery_inner'>";
    // the loop, keep the ul outside of the loop
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getimg))
    {
        echo "<li class='loaded'>"; 
        echo "<a href='IMAGES/" . $row['imagename'] . "'></a></li>";
     }
     echo "</ul>";
}
else
{
    echo "Images not available.";
}
```

**Note:** [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: Thanks Sheikh.  That worked. Only problem I have now is that the images are not loading.  Do you know what would lead to this problem?  When I copy and paste the links it shows up but they aren't in the gallery.

Comment: Images path could be wrong, Maybe you can use absolute `url` like `http://yourdomain.com/pathtoimagesfolder/$row['imagename']`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP renders wherever the script is executed. Therefore, if you have echo tags inside your dyna.php page, it will output to that file.

What you want to do is send a request to that script and then print the response, which will be the echo'd content of your script. The most common way to print contents of an external script is using AJAX, which allows you to send requests and capture responses in javascript (or jQuery) without having to reload the page you are on.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

If you're using jQuery, the easiest way to insert the response html into a div is using the html() function: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp

```
$('#gallery').html(responseHTML);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at using the jQuery method. The only problem I am having with that is I am unsure of how to capture the information on the php file.

Answer (score 0):

A alternative from Sheikh Heera:

```
$getimg = mysqli_query($connection,"your query") or die(mysqli_error());
if($getimg) {
// ID should be unique, so use 'gallery_inner' because parent div's ID is gallery
echo '<ul id="gallery_inner">';
// the loop, keep the ul outside of the loop
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getimg))
{
    echo '<li class="loaded">
    <a href="IMAGES/'. $row['imagename'] .'"></a></li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';} else { echo 'Images not available.';}
```